# ClojureScript mangling names differently for the same kind of code in advanced optimizations

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clojurescript

This is a piece of code for a Chrome extension.

I am starting with ClojureScript, so this might be some trivial problem, and though I have found the solution, I still don't understand why the problem happens.

This is the piece of code that grinds my gears:

```
(defn print-and-save-selection
  [info tab]
  (let [selection-text (.-selectionText info)]
    (println info) ;; => #js { bunch of properties, "selectionText" being one }
    (.get js/chrome.storage.sync
          (clj->js {:history nil :historyItems []})
          (fn [items]
            (println items)  ;; => #js {:history nil :historyItems #js []}
            (let [history-items (.-historyItems items)
                  updated-history-items (.concat history-items selection-text)]
              (println updated-history-items)  ;; => correct list in :whitespace mode
              ;; save stuff using other chrome.storage function
```

I have my externs properly set and this code works correctly under `:whitespace` optimiziations, but not under `:advanced`. For the latter, it gaves me a **"Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined"**. In other words, `(.-historyItems)` fails to find the appropriate element inside `items`. If I change this to `(aget items "historyItems")` it works, even in `:advanced`.

What I can't understand is why the functionality that works for `(.-selectionText info)` (third line) does not work for `(.-historyItems items)`, when both of them are accessing a property of a JavaScript object. This might be related to the level of nestedness of this code?

For completeness, the generated code is something like this:

**:advanced without aget**

```
var a = b.selectionText;
...
// a few nested returns and functions ...
    var h = g.Ab, c = h.concat(a);  // => error mentioned above
```

**:advanced with aget**

```
var a = b.selectionText;
...
// a few nested returns and functions ...
    var h = g.historyItems, c = h.concat(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it was a trivial matter.

It turns out that the `selectionText` property is defined in the externs file, while the `historyItems` is set in chrome's storage by me. Because of that, the same style of code leads to different behavior.

**Conclusion:** what really matters is what is defined in the externs file.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! :) Need to wait a few days before SO lets you accept your own answer.